# How I can ban someone with Python and discord.py?

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to implement some feature where if someone sends a Discord invite, they get banned, but I get the same error every time:

```
'BotLibertarin' object has no attribute 'ban'
```

Here is the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class BotLibertarin(discord.Client):
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
    @client.event   
    async def on_ready(self):
       print(f"Logged on as {self.user}")

    @client.event
    async def on_message(self, message):
        print(f"message from {message.author} what he said {message.content} and the id is {message.author.id}")
       if message.author == client.user:
           return
      #ban for invinte on discord
    if message.content.startswith("https://discord.gg/"):
        for member in client.get_all_members():
            print("entrou dentro do if")
            if member.id == message.author.id:
                print("vai tomar ban KKKKKK")
                banned = member.id

                try:
                    await client.ban(banned,delete_message_days=2)
                    await message.channel.send(f"User {banned} sended a discord invite")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"you got error {e}")
client = BotLibertarin()
client.run("")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using syntax from a version of discord.py, v0.16, that isn't supported anymore.
See [the guide for migrating to v1](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html), specifically the [Models are Stateful section](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#models-are-stateful).

You should use [`Member.ban`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.ban) or [`Guild.ban`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.ban) rather than `Client.ban`.
In this case, the relevant line would be `await member.ban(delete_message_days=2)`.

Also, in the future, when asking for help, you should provide the full traceback.

Comment: i just did a lillte change ond that used member and i got this error:ban() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: It's impossible to determine what your exact issue is without a full traceback, but you shouldn't be passing any positional arguments to [`Member.ban`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.ban).